# User column option disabled for user in Organization Settings -> Usage

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to grant a user access to view the User column information underneath of Usage inside of Organization Settings, but that specific column is grayed out unless I elevate their permissions to Project Collection Administrator. Where is this permission controlled and can access to this information be granted without elevating the user to Project Collection Administrator?

I am able to see these options under Column Options:

[image]

The user can only see these options under Column Options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Project Collection Administrator permission is required to view User Column. When the User column is available, it means that the member is able to investigate the usage of other users. This is currently designed to PCA only. Refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=vsts#user-experience) for details.

> For members of the project collection administrators group, this same
>   page can be used to investigate the usage of other users.